# Can't load the entire scss of Foundation 6 with Webpack

Tags: javascript, sass, zurb-foundation, webpack, zurb-foundation-6

I try to load Foundation 6 scss with Webpack.

Here's my very simple `main.scss` file:

```
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';

body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here's the call in my `app.js`:

```
import './main.scss';  //webpack syntax
```

And here's my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: './app/app.js',

    resolve: {
        root: [__dirname + "/src"],
        moduleDirectories: [__dirname + '/node_modules']
    },

    externals: {
        jQuery: 'jQuery',
        foundation: 'Foundation'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                loader: "babel"
            },
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass!'},
            {test: /\.html$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "raw"}

        ]
    },

    // support source maps
    devtool: "#inline-source-map"

};
```

After running `webpack-dev-server --content-base src/`,
the resulting `index.html` file contains this:

[image]

Why are there **only** the initial comments of Foundation's scss ?
May it be a bug of `sass-loader`?

I can't load all the entire Foundation's scss file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537431/foundation-6-does-not-generate-any-styles

Comment: Wow !!! the same exact example ! amazing :)

Comment: I noticed that too, crazy coincidence lol.

Comment: Really !! and answer really obvious by the way :) Thanks for the link.