# Correct Way to customize zurb foundation 6 with bower

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Using zurb foundation 6 with bower, what is the normal workflow to customize it using the _settings.scss file, so that the file doesn't stay in the bower_components folder.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537431/foundation-6-does-not-generate-any-styles) says that we could copy the settings file and then import it in our app.scss.

In my custom scss folder, I have made a settings.scss file using the _settings file as template, but in that case I also have to copy the entire utils folder as the settings file imports that.(or change the import path of the utils folder to the one in bower_components).

Is there a better way to do this ??

**Edit**

I am using gulp to compile the sass files.

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {

    gulp.src('./app/sass/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))

})
```

And this is what app.scss looks like right now (foundation.scss is a file which imports the scss files from inside the bower_components, while settings is a clone of the _settings file with some changes)

```
@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';

@include foundation-global-styles;
// @include foundation-grid;
@include foundation-flex-grid;
// @include foundation-typography;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely want to copy the settings file out of the `bower_components` directory. Then you should add `bower_components/foundation-sites/scss` to your import paths where you compile the SCSS and that will take care of the `utils` issue. The import path needs to be in the options object inside of the gulp-sass pipe like so:

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {

    gulp.src('./app/sass/app.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation-sites/scss']
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat('style.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app'))
})
```

When you use the `includePaths` option, imports will check for files relative to the current directory, followed by files relative to the directories in the `includePaths` array. `@import util/util` works after adding `bower_components/foundation-sites/scss` to the `includePaths` because the full path is `bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/util/_util.scss`.

Comment: thanks colin, i have added some code to the question .. i also tried adding 'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss' separately to my gulp task, but the problem seems to be that in the settings file, it directly uses '@import utils/utils'

Comment: And btw, your `concat` pipe is useless because your source is one file so there's no files to join together. Everything is imported in the sass.

Comment: thanks.. this works perfectly.. is this a standard way of including bower components, so if i include another component that uses sass, i just add its path to the `includePaths` property to resolve dependencies? (i had added that concat pipe to include foundation there as well, but i guess it is useless now .. thanks for the heads up )

Comment: Yes, you can include other components by adding it to the `includePaths` array. It saves a good amount of code because you don't need to include the path in your `@import` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Easier:

1. Move the default `bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss` file into your own project styles.
2. Edit `_settings.scss` file to your liking.
3. Go to `bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss` file:

Replace:

```
// Settings
// import your own `settings` here or
// import and modify the default settings through
// @import 'settings';
```

With:

```
// Settings
// import your own `settings` here or
// import and modify the default settings through
@import 'your_own/project/styles/path/settings';
```

4. Make sure foundation is being imported on your styles:

`@import "bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss";`

5. Voilà!