# Compiling foundation SASS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, zurb-foundation, laravel-elixir, zurb-foundation-6

I cannot compile foundation for sites.

```
mix.sass('site/app.scss', null, { includePaths: ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/']}
```

Then in app.scss I import the various files:

```
@import 'util/util';
....
```

The compiled .css file does not contain any foundation stuff, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Removing elixir tag from this question because the user wants the laravel-elixir tag on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foundation 6 does not generate any styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537431/foundation-6-does-not-generate-any-styles)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537431/foundation-6-does-not-generate-any-styles/34538606#34538606