# Gulp & Foundation 6 not compiling

Tags: css, gulp, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use foundation sites in my project so I downloaded it using bower.

I have a gulp.config.js file which has the following code:

```
module.exports = function() {
  // PATHS TO JS AND SASS
  var GETPATHS = {
    VENDOR: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
    ],
    JS: [
      'bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js',
      'src/assets/**/*.js'
    ],
    SASS: [
      'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
      'src/assets/scss/components'
    ]
  }
  return GETPATHS;
}
```

and my gulpfile itself has this (SASS):

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/assets/scss/app.scss')
      .pipe(sass({ includePaths: config.SASS }))
      .pipe(autoprefixer())
      .pipe(cssnano())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('_build/assets/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

and here's my app.scss file

```
@import "foundation";
```

Now, the problem is I don't know why app.css (after getting compiled) is showing an empty file. The import "foundation" doesn't seem to work. Any help is appreciated as I am quite new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a *foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss* file?

Comment: Yes, there's a foundation.scss file in the scss folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foundation 6 does not generate any styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537431/foundation-6-does-not-generate-any-styles)

Comment: @VividuaElsaphe you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34537431/foundation-6-does-not-generate-any-styles/34538606#34538606

Answer (score 0):

I suggest installing one of the Foundation Sites templates or using the foundation cli to bootstrap a project and get the needed file with all imports.

foundation.scss just contains the mixins.
You can see an example for the right config at https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/src/assets/scss/app.scss and https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites-template/blob/master/scss/app.scss

Also see [Gulp & Foundation 6 not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074885/gulp-foundation-6-not-compiling#comment61734810_37074885)